# The replaceAll method is not working for me what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, string, replaceall

I run the code but it does not replace string1 with string2

I tried combing the scanners but that did not work. I tried making the scanners close separately but the resulted in a syntax error of course.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Remove_and_Replace {
public static void main(String []args) {
      Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter your first word:");
      String String1 = a.nextLine();
      Scanner b = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter your second word:");
      String String2 = b.nextLine();
      Scanner c = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter your sentence:");
      String String3 = c.nextLine();
      c.close();

      String replaceString=String3.replaceAll("String1","String2");
     System.out.println(replaceString); 
    }
}
```

Expected Results:

```
Enter your first word:
bad
Enter your second word:
good
Enter your sentence:
I am always bad.
I am always good.
```

Actual Results:

```
Enter your first word:
bad
Enter your second word:
good
Enter your sentence:
I am always bad.
I am always bad.
```

Comment: None of your input has the string `String1`. I think you may have read some documentation or a tutorial ... a bit too literally. Reading the API docs for `replaceAll` might be a good idea: it tells you what the parameters *mean*. Honestly I'm at somewhat of a loss.

Comment: your are replacing "String1" string with "String2" string not their variables.

Comment: Another problem with your code that is outside of the immediate scope of your question but that you should soon encounter : don't define 3 scanners on the same input ; only define one and read lines 3 times from that one.

Comment: That obviously a good example why one need to name a variable with a bit sense.

Comment: Please note javas naming convention. Variable names should always be in camelCase, not PascalCase.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the double-quotes:

```
  String replaceString=String3.replaceAll(String1, String2);
```

**Explanation**:

With your original line, you are replacing *literally* the word *String1* with the word *String2*. Without the double-quotes, you are replacing the word stored in the `String1` variable (bad) with the word stored in `String2` variable (good). On a side note, Java naming conventions specify that **variables** start with a lowercase letter - upper-case are used for **Classes**.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
String replaceString=String3.replaceAll("String1","String2");
```

Should be replaced by:

```
String replaceString=String3.replaceAll(String1, String2);
```

In the first line you're trying to replace the value "String1" itself, instead of using the object.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use String1, String2 in quotes?

Replace this:

```
  String replaceString=String3.replaceAll("String1","String2");
```

With this:

```
  String replaceString=String3.replaceAll(String1,String2);
```

BTW, According to the naming conventions, variables are always named starting with the lower-case letter. so it should all look like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your first word:");
    String firstWord = a.nextLine();
    Scanner b = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your second word:");
    String secondWord = b.nextLine();
    Scanner c = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your sentence:");
    String sentence = c.nextLine();
    c.close();

    String updatedSentence = sentence.replaceAll(firstWord, secondWord);
    System.out.println(updatedSentence);
}
```

More on that you can read here: https://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the quotation marks from the method. What happens is it's looking for a word "String1" and if it finds said word it will replace it with the word "String2". Removing the quotes makes it so it will look for the object's reference instead of the actual variable name.

This: `String replaceString=String3.replaceAll("String1", "String2");`

Should become this: `String replaceString=String3.replaceAll(String1,String2);`

Answer (score -1):

```
String replaceString = String3.replaceAll(String1,String2);
```

Chang like this and  print replacestring,you will get answer